# Perl6 String Concatenation Hangs

Tags: concatenation, raku

I'm trying to concatenate a string with Perl6 thus:

```
my $cmd = "databricks jobs --job-id 37 --notebook-params '\{";
put $cmd;
$cmd ,= "\"directory\": \"$s3-dir\",";
put $cmd;
```

However, the output hangs after the `,=` operator.  I'm assuming that this works the same way from the Perl `.=` operator.

https://docs.perl6.org/language/operators

Why is this job hanging? how can I properly concatenate the string?

Comment: "*I'm assuming that this works the same way from the Perl `.=` operator.*" ... Why?

Comment: @melpomene because that's what the manual made it look like

Comment: https://docs.perl6.org/language/operators#infix_~, https://docs.perl6.org/language/operators#Assignment_operators

Comment: As far as I can tell, `$cmd ,= "..."` is equivalent to `$cmd = ($cmd, "...")`, which creates a pair whose first element is a reference to the same pair (a self-referential structure). `say $cmd` shows as much, but `put` tries to convert the whole thing to a string by traversing an infinite structure (which hangs).

Comment: @melpomene yes, the correct answer is that Perl5's `.=` should be `~=` in Perl6.  If you can put this down as an answer, I'll accept it.  I didn't see this in the manual because that section doesn't have "concatenate" written in it :/

Comment: Yeah, the manual is confusing. I'll wait for someone who actually knows/uses Perl6 to write an answer. I'm just making educated guesses.

Comment: If you also raise an issue in the docs, I'll be very grateful for that.

Comment: @jjmerelo it is Issue #2597 https://github.com/perl6/doc/issues/2597

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no `,=` or `~=` operators in Perl6.

Those are instances of the `=` meta operator combined with another infix operator.

```perl6
# these are all functionally equivalent:
$a = $a ~ 'a';
$a ~= 'a';
$a [~]= 'a';
$a [&[~]]= 'a';
$a [&infix:<~>]= 'a';

$a = infix:<~> $a, 'a'; # use an operator as a subroutine
```

---

There is a history of C-like languages having operators like `+=`.
It would get a little tiring having to define new operators like that for every infix operator.
In Perl6 you can also easily define new operators.
So it has `=` as a meta-operator that will automatically work with all infix operators.

```perl6
sub infix:<foo> (\l,\r){…}

$a = $a foo 3;
$a foo= 3;
$a [foo]= 3;
```

---

If you want to use an operator like `+=`, just look for the base operator that matches what you want and add `=`.

If you want to do string concatenation, the base operator is the infix `~` operator.
(Which looks a lot like the string coercion prefix operator `~`.)

```perl6
$a = $a ~ 'a';
$a ~= 'a';
```

If you want to do Set difference, the base operator is `(-)`.

```perl6
$a = $a (-) 3;
$a (-)= 3;
```

---

You can add any number of `[]` surrounding an infix operator.
(It needs space before it so that it isn't confused with postcircumfix `[]`)

```perl6
$a     -     3;
$a    [-]    3;
$a   [[-]]   3;
$a  [[[-]]]  3;
```

Which can be useful to make sure that meta operators combine the way you want them too.

```perl6
$a -=         3;
$a [-]=       3;
3  R-=       $a; # $a = $a - 3;
$a [R-]=      3; # $a = 3 - $a;
3  R[-=]     $a; # $a = $a - 3;
3  R[[R-]=]  $a; # $a = 3 - $a;
```

This was extended so that `[&…]` where `&…` is the name of a function works as an infix operator.

```perl6
sub bar (\l,\r){…}

# these are functionally identical.
$a = bar( $a, 3 );
$a = $a [&bar] 3;
$a [&bar]= 3;
```

---

When you used `,=` you created a self-referential data structure.
(Note that `say` calls `.gist`, I added an extra `.gist` to be extra clear that I'm not printing a `Str`.)

```perl6
my $c = 0;
# $c ,= 1;
$c = ($c,1);

say $c.gist;
# (\List_94195670785568 = (List_94195670785568 1))

say $c.WHICH;
# List|94195670785568
```

When you do something that coerces a `List` or `Array` into a `Str`, it follows the structure turning each part into a `Str`.

```perl6
$c = ($c,…);

~$c;
# $c.Str
# |     \___________________
# |                         \
# $c[0].Str ~ ' ' ~ $c[1].Str
# |        \        \        \__________ 
# |    |    \        \__________________ 1.Str
# |    |     \
# |    V      \_____________
# |                         \
# $c[0].Str ~ ' ' ~ $c[1].Str
# |        \        \        \__________ 
# |    |    \        \__________________ 1.Str
# |    |     \
# |    V      \_____________
# |                         \
# $c[0].Str ~ ' ' ~ $c[1].Str
# |        \        \        \__________ 
# |    |    \        \__________________ 1.Str
# |    |     \
# |    V      \_____________
# |                         \
# …
```

It of course never finishes turning the first part into a Str.

---

The combination of `,` and `=` works safely with a Hash though.
(Which is what the docs show.)

```perl6
my %c = a => 0;
%c ,= b => 1;
# %c = (%c, b => 1)

say %c.gist;
# {a => 0, b => 1}
```

Answer (score 4):

There was some confusion in the manual.

```
my $cmd = "databricks jobs --job-id 37 --notebook-params '\{";
put $cmd;
$cmd ,= "\"directory\": \"$s3-dir\",";
put $cmd;
```

should be

```
my $cmd = "databricks jobs --job-id 37 --notebook-params '\{";
put $cmd;
$cmd ~= "\"directory\": \"$s3-dir\",";
put $cmd;
```

the proper way to concatenate an already declared variable in Perl6 is with `~=`